# Very simple Spring MVC sample with thymeleaf not working

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am very disappointed, I followed a tutorial on how to add Thymeleaf to a Spring MVC project but it doesn't even work with a 3-classes sample project. Thymeleaf cannot find my views and I don't know what I am missing.

> Stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/test.html]")
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

> **SpringMVCConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "main.java" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMVCConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
   @Bean
   public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
      SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
      templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      return templateResolver;
   }
   @Bean
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
      templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
      return templateEngine;
   }
   @Override
   public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
      ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
      registry.viewResolver(resolver);
   }
}
```

> **DispatcherServletConfiguration.class**

```
public class DispatcherServletConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringMVCConfiguration.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

> **TestController.class**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(Model model) {
        System.out.println("controller test");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, the HTML file is located here :

```
-- Project
    -- WebContent
        -- WEB-INF
            -- views
                - test.html
```

> **test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get off the ground running faster, I would suggest using spring-boot with its thyme-leaf starter.  It handles most of the frustrating wiring code to avoid these issues.

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/

Per your code, I'm guessing your component scan is wrong.  Can you switch it from main.java to the root of your package hierarchy... whatever that is?  Its probably the package name that the main.java file is in.

Also, maybe try moving your WEB-INF to `src/main/web-app/WEB-INF`?

Comment: Spring boot is working fine but unfortunately I am trying to use Spring MVC vanilla with Thymeleaf only. Thing is when I look at exploded WAR in Tomcat webapp there is nothing but java classes in the WEB-INF folder so it is logic it returns that it cannot fetch the HTML file. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't pack html files into the WAR.

Comment: I would generally expect to see WEF-INF under src/main/web-app/WEB-INF.

Comment: I got it, I had to add this line to maven-war-plugin. Don't know what is it necessary now though :
`<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>`

Comment: I think that's the same issue.  You used a non-standard location so you had to override it.  Is it working now?

Comment: Yes it is working fine now. By "non-standard" you mean I should have a "webapp" folder instead of "WebContent" (Tomcat)? Or that I should use the recommended folder structure "webapp/template" ?